# Given a condition on $n$ reals

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_1,a_2 \cdots a_n$ be reals such that $$\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2-1}+ \cdots +\sqrt{a_n-(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n)-\frac{n(n-3)}{4}$$ Find the sum of the first $100$ terms of the sequence. I am just unable to think what to do. Pleae give some hints and ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You post really good questions ^^

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2-1} + \ldots + \sqrt{a_n-(n-1)}$?

Comment: Oh, I am flattered. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks.

Comment: 5050. Gauss' answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @You-know-me he means that $a_n = n$.

Comment: Oh, it is a mere guess. Though, the answer is correct.

Comment: @You-know-me you can prove it by induction, I suppose

Comment: @You-know-me I don't think it is a guess ;)

Answer (score 8):

Using A.M-G.M inequality
$$\sqrt{a_i-(i-1)} \leq \frac{a_i-i+2}{2}$$
Therefore
$$\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2-1}+ \cdots +\sqrt{a_n-(n-1)}\leq\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n)-\frac{n(n-3)}{4}$$

But we know equality in fact holds. So, $a_i = i$.

Comment: And indeed Gauss' answer was right :)

Comment: That's really clever! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

`Slightly' longer answer :)

I'll skip the base part of the MI. So, it is true for some $k$.
$$
\sum \limits_{i = 1}^k \sqrt{a_i - (i - 1)} = \frac 12 \sum \limits_{i = 1}^k a_i - \frac {k(k - 3)}4
$$
Now, let's observe what happens if we take $k + 1$ terms
$$
\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k+1} \sqrt{a_i - (i - 1)} = \frac 12 \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k+1} a_i - \frac {(k+1)(k - 2)}4
$$
Now, use the equality for the $k$ terms in LHS
$$
\frac 12 \sum \limits_{i = 1}^k a_i - \frac {k(k - 3)}4 + \sqrt{a_{k+1}-k} = \frac 12 \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k+1} a_i - \frac {(k+1)(k - 2)}4 \implies \\
\sqrt{a_{k+1} - k} = \frac {a_{k+1}}2 - \frac 14\left [{(k+1)(k-2) - k(k-3)} \right ] = \frac {a_{k+1}}2 - \frac 12(k-1) \implies \\
4 (a_{k+1} - k) = a_{k+1}^2 - 2a_{k+1}(k-1) + (k-1)^2 \implies\\
a_{k+1}^2 - 2a_{k+1}(k-1+2) + (k-1)^2 + 4k = a_{k+1}^2 - 2a_{k+1}(k+1) + (k+1)^2 = 0 \implies \\
a_{k+1} = k+1
$$